# NextJS: How to add bootstrap via CDN

Tags: next.js, cdn

I am new to nextJS and I am having a bad time including bootstrap in the app via CDN. Where to add the links is best practice in the app?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Include Head from `./next` and use declare any links to be included there.

```
     <Head>
         <script src="https://...."/>      
     </Head>
```

Comment: as of 08/01/2021 it is a best practice to put the keyword async before the src prop => see docs https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/script#usage

Answer (score 12):

To override the default Document, create the file `./pages/_document.js` and extend the Document class as shown below and put CDN path between `HEAD` tag.

Refer [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-document) for more info

```
import Document, { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from "next/document";

class MyDocument extends Document {
  static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
    const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx);
    return { ...initialProps };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Html>
        <Head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous" />
        </Head>
        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </Html>
    );
  }
}

export default MyDocument;
```

you just need to make it a closed tag

Comment: Is it any different from including those in <Head> in _app.js

Comment: i did not get you.

Comment: Right now I added `<links>` inside the `<Head>` component of my _app.js file so are they any different?

Comment: is it working??? still i am unable to get you. this [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-document) may answer your question

Answer (score 1):

If you are using next js 13

then goto your layout.js and you can add your external cdn file (css here for example ) in RootLayout function like this

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="your CDN link path"></link>
  </head>
  <body >
  </body>
</html>
```

Note: Do not forget to close link tag as in above example.

Answer (score 0):

It is preferable to add third-party scripts in the [Script](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/script) tag for better performance, as mentioned in the [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/script).

> The Next.js Script component, next/script, is an extension of the HTML
>
> element. It enables developers to set the loading priority of
> third-party scripts anywhere in their application without needing to
> append directly to next/head, saving developer time while improving
> loading performance.

Answer (score 0):

For Next.js 14 App router , go to the `layout.tsx` file inside `app` directory.

Paste your CSS link tag in the `head` tag and JavaScript file inside `body` or html tag with the help of the Next.js `Script` component.

**Eg :**

```
import type { Metadata } from "next";
import { Inter } from "next/font/google";
import "./globals.css";

// Script component
import Script from "next/script";

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] });

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: "Create Next App",
  description: "Generated by create next app",
};

export default function RootLayout({
 children,
}: Readonly<{
 children: React.ReactNode;
}>) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      
      <head>
       
        <link
          href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          rel="stylesheet"
          integrity="sha384-9ndCyUaIbzAi2FUVXJi0CjmCapSmO7SnpJef0486qhLnuZ2cdeRhO02iuK6FUUVM"
          crossOrigin="anonymous"
        />

      </head>

      <body className={inter.className}>{children}</body>

      <Script
        src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-geWF76RCwLtnZ8qwWowPQNguL3RmwHVBC9FhGdlKrxdiJJigb/j/68SIy3Te4Bkz"
        crossOrigin="anonymous"
      />

    </html>
  );
}
```