# NextJS use Bootstrap styles from CDN with storybook

Tags: html, next.js, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5, storybook

I would like to preface this post by saying that I not too experienced with frontend tech.

For some brief context, I am trying to configure Storybook with a NextJS project which uses styles from custom CSS and Bootstrap. The Bootstrap libraries are configured to be [pulled from a CDN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66029308/nextjs-how-to-add-bootstrap-via-cdn) on the client side. This has been configured in the [`src/pages/_document.tsx` file](https://gist.github.com/Abyiss-Zach/b57b218668df1790c0981e640c9125b3). This works fine in dev/production. Apparently we are using two version of Bootstrap (5.2 and 4.0.0). The team that worked on this app before me left this (Hopefully this is not causing the problem).

Now with the context out of the way, the problem comes in when I initialize Storybook. The default config only appears to be rendering the custom (non-bootstrap) css. I can see in the Firefox dev tools network tab that there are no calls to the CDNs when a story is rendered. I read that this can be solved by creating a `.storybook/preview-head.html` file and putting the links/scripts from `_document.tsx` into there. So I did this, restarted storybook, and was faced with empty components on Storybook that will not render in. However, I can see that in the network tab that there are successful requests being made to the CDN. I also read that a similar effect can be achieved by creating `manager-head.html` but this just makes Storybook render with a blank white screen. Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated!

Tech stack:

- Next 13.1.1
- Typescript 4.4.4
- Storybook 7.0.6
- @storybook/addon-styling 1.0.1
- @storybook/testing-library: 0.0.14-next.2
- Bootstrap 5.2 and 4.0.0 via config in _document.tsx:

  - 5.2:

  ```
   <link
     href='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
     rel='stylesheet'
     integrity='sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx'
     crossOrigin='anonymous'
   />
   <script
     defer
     src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js'
     integrity='sha384-A3rJD856KowSb7dwlZdYEkO39Gagi7vIsF0jrRAoQmDKKtQBHUuLZ9AsSv4jD4Xa'
     crossOrigin='anonymous'
   />
  ```

  - 4.0.0

  ```
      <script
         defer
         src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js'
         integrity='sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN'
         crossOrigin='anonymous'
       />
       <script
         defer
         src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js'
         integrity='sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q'
         crossOrigin='anonymous'
       />
       <script
         defer
         src='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js'
         integrity='sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl'
         crossOrigin='anonymous'
       />
  ```

`/.storybook/preview.ts`:

```
    import type { Preview } from '@storybook/react'
    import '../src/styles/globals.css'
    import React from 'react'
    
    // This Block fixes rendering images that use the NextImage tag in Storybook
    import * as NextImage from 'next/image';
    const OriginalNextImage = NextImage.default;
    Object.defineProperty(NextImage, 'default', {
      configurable: true,
      value: (props) =>
        React.createElement(OriginalNextImage, { ...props, unoptimized: true }),
    })
    
    const preview: Preview = {
      parameters: {
        actions: { argTypesRegex: '^on[A-Z].*' },
        controls: {
          matchers: {
            color: /(background|color)$/i,
            date: /Date$/,
          },
        },
      },
    };
    
    export default preview
```

`/.storybook/main.ts`:

```
    import type { StorybookConfig } from '@storybook/nextjs'
    const config: StorybookConfig = {
      stories: ['../src/**/*.mdx', '../src/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)'],
      addons: [
        '@storybook/addon-links',
        '@storybook/addon-essentials',
        '@storybook/addon-interactions',
        '@storybook/addon-styling',
      ],
      framework: {
        name: '@storybook/nextjs',
        options: {},
      },
      docs: {
        autodocs: 'tag',
      },
    };
    export default config
```

Here is an example of the css render issue:

- What storybook renders:
- [image: This is what I am seeing in storybook1]
- What I expect storybook to render:
- [image: This is what I expect storybook to render]

Comment: NextJS uses SSR, so you can't just add Bootstrap CDN links. See: [How can I use Bootstrap 5 with Next.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67845378/13138364)

Comment: Also it's definitely not a good idea to mix BS4 and BS5.